# Calculate date from today and change color of text for like after 7days

Tags: javascript

I want to write a javascript that will calculate age from submittal date to today and  if the item is more than 5days old will change color of text to yellow and red if its more than 10days old.

```html
<p>text<p>
<input type="date" id="date" name="date">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Everyone is itching to just solve this, but the idea is you try first and ask questions why it's not working and then we help. At the very least explain what you think the logic would be to accomplish it.

Comment: Using Moment js should solve your problem. https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/07-difference/ should actually help.

Comment: Thanks guys. I am still learning javascript and I have this table on excel that we use to calc the days and I was thinking of  how would it look in javascript. would it be something I can understand at my level or is it that complicated, I have no idea at the moment but I am checking on resources that can lead me on solving this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<html>
<body>
 <p>Your Age Calc<p>
 <form method="GET">
   <input type="date" id="date" name="date">
   <button type="button" id="mybutton">Submit</button>
 </form>
 <div id="result"></div>
<script type="application/javascript">

function showResult() {
 let result =  document.getElementById("result")
 let date = document.getElementById("date");
 if (date.value === "" ) {
  result.innerHTML = "Please input a correct date, !";
  } else {
    let birthday = new Date (`${date.value}`)
    let ageDifMs = Date.now() - birthday.getTime();
    let num_days = ((ageDifMs % 31536000000) % 2628000000)/86400000;
    num_days > 10 ? result.style.color = "green" : result.style.color = "blue"
    result.innerHTML = " Your age(days), " + num_days.toFixed(1);
  }
}

document.getElementById("mybutton").onclick = showResult;

</script>
</body>
</html>
```